# Is there expiry for work tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

There are so many work tables which are created some many days back and not dropped yet and tempdb was stocked.

Regards

Comment: What? *If* you mean temporary tables, then they only exist for the duration of the scope that they were created in. If you create an object in `tempbd` (i.e. `USE TempBD; CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int);` then it'll be there till you `DROP` it, or the instance is restarted (and `tempdb` is rebuilt).

Comment: Actual work tables (which are created by SQL Server during queries) only persist for the duration of the query. So if they were created "days ago" they won't exist anymore.